# Scooter won't start

Tags: starting, scooter

My friend has a Chinese 50cc scooter "VIP Future Champion" that won't start. He let the battery run down when it was still operable, over a year ago, and when he finally replaced the battery, it wouldn't start with the electric starter or the kick start. There are at least several things wrong with it, probably all stemming from storing it outside unused for a long period.

There's no continuity through the electric starter button when it's pressed. Shorting across the terminals that go to the button does not make the starter operate either. However, I'm guessing this is just a matter of chewed or rusted wires, since running a wire from the positive battery terminal straight to the starter motor does make it turn over, but it still doesn't ignite and run.

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the ignition system. I was able to produce a spark from the end of the spark plug wire to the chassis, and the ground seems good everywhere.

There are a couple disconnected hoses that seem to be intake related, but with no obvious places to attach them. One was full of mess that looked like some sort of insect had tried to build a nest inside. I don't have pictures at the moment but I could probably take some tomorrow/soon.

Oh, and in case it's not obvious, we did put new fuel in it.

At this point, my biggest problem is that I'm not at all familiar with scooters and don't know what to try or where to look for problems. I searched online but couldn't find anything similar to a Haynes manual for it, or any resources with good pictures and/or disassembly/repair instructions to know what I'm looking at and what I'm doing. Can anyone suggest where we should start looking for a solution?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Doesn't the last paragraph address that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your last paragraph is the question, I think it is far too broad. You would be best off getting the manual and with its help:

- reconnecting anything that should be connected
- cleaning anything dirty or full of insects etc
- check continuity of all wires individually and replace any that are faulty
- check spark plugs
- check air inlets
- move all mechanical parts and lubricate as necessary

You see why I think it is too broad a question? There are so many things that could be wrong. Try the above items first, then if there is a specific problem, this site can be much more useful.

**Update** Here are an engine manual and a wiring diagram, found by googling the name of your scooter. http://www.chinesescooterreference.com/pdf/GY6Manual.pdf and http://www.chinesescooterreference.com/manuals_charts.htm

Comment: We have the manual that came with the scooter, and it doesn't contain anything about diagnosis or repair. As I mentioned at the end of the question, I've been unable to find any third-party repair manual, so help finding one would be a good answer to the question.

Comment: I wouldn't have expected the manual to have diagnosis instructions, but I would expect it to have a parts list and locations for each? If not, I googled your scooter type and found PDF manuals for engine and electrics, so the information is freely available.

Comment: There is a parts list manual, but it's just very poor drawings.

Comment: Thanks for the update. It looks like the manual you provided a link to might help.

Comment: So far your answer has been pretty helpful. After lots of random tinkering, we've gotten it to start, but it immediately dies. I'm still trying to find a complete diagram of the fuel system, as there are a few components which I don't even recognize, much less know how to diagnose.

Answer (score 2):

Check intake + exhaust valves, thay aerial more than likely the problem. they have to be set every 1000 miles, otherwise no start or hard start in cold.

Answer (score 1):

I have a 2012 Jonway Gator yy50qt-6 and had the same starting issues. I had to replace the rectifier which is located in the front of your bike, mounted just above the horn. Also, there are 2 glass fuses coming from your battery. If they are blown, the scooter will not start. I hope this information is useful to you good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If the vehicle sits for more then 6-month then the petrol is out of date.  Since there is a new way to make petrol it will have a best date of approximately 6-9 months.

There is an easy way to see this.  Take a small glass and poor in some petrol 2dl, and wait for 5min.  If you see petrol in 2 layers then the petrol is bad and your motor wont start.

Answer (score -1):

With the Chinese made scooter, my experience was that it needs to run on RON95 or above (Octane rating). Try that.

Answer (score -1):

Any time you don't use any vehicle for a wile you are going to have issues of not getting to start but the type of unit could be the difference like the scooters for instance or motorcycles will be the worst of all. the scooter will be the carburetor, electrical and lots more. Get a new battery and have the carburetor rebuilt. It might be the problem.