# Two hoses that run from the carburetor - Is the upper hose cut and zip tied? Is that's the one that brings fuel to the carburetor?

Tags: maintenance, scooter

I bought a [VIP Future Champion](http://www.motor-scooters-guide.com/2009-peace-sports-vip-future-champion-49cc-bash-scooter-review.html), took it to the shop and had the heads changed because the mechanic said it had bad heads, so 200 dollars later... I went in to pick it up and the mechanic says there is a knock in the lower engine, he starts it up (it starts right up) and lets it run for about 30 seconds, so my friend and I go outside to talk and decide to take it home rather than pay the additional 200 dollars.

We go in to get the scooter and suddenly it won't start. I think the mechanic was shady and did something very simple to keep it from starting. It's hot and I'm tired of walking after spending 1000 bucks on a scooter. Why wouldn't it start and hasn't started since?

The mechanic said there was a knock in the lower engine, but he started it right up to show us. It doesn't ignite, but tries to start..

I just assumed it might be something simple, because my past experience with shady auto mechanics is like with my [Ford Taurus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford_Taurus) for which the mechanic flipped the fuel pump relay switch in the trunk without my knowledge and acted as if it wouldn't start... Then the next day I went to get my car tired of giving the guy my money and he had a fake mechanics lean drawn up and... Well, long story...

Anyway, I assumed that since he started it right up and two mins later it didn't after I went outside with my boyfriend and decided I wasn't given him any more money, that maybe there was something simple and stupid like that? Should I have left my scooter in the shop and given him another 200 dollars? The starter works fine and everything else seems to work except it just won't get going or turn all the way over or run.

It's in my back yard right now. The battery is fully charged, and I tried starting it a couple of minutes ago. I'm sitting outside with my laptop and my scooter. Oh What would be a couple of ways to maybe troubleshoot and figure out the problem?

Am I correct in that the upper hose that leaves the fuel pump go to the front of the carburetor? And the lower hose to the back?

Comment: Does the starter run and it won't start or does it just click or does it not do anything at all when trying to start it?

Comment: sad story with no question, lol this s true. I up voted because this can be a great question and other people might benefit from getting ripped off, IF it develops with a good answer etc...

Comment: it sounds like it wants to start but doesnt turn all the way like its not getting any fire

Comment: @hannah: please give more detailed information about all the mechanical issues in question that you know. If you think he is shady and taking advantage of you, get your scooter out of there and research a better mechanic.

Comment: It might be helpful to edit the title of your question to include your starting issue in the question.  It is kind of generic right now and some people might skip by it because of that.

Comment: Do you smell gas after attempting to start the scooter for a while?

Answer (score 4):

The first things to check that come to mind...

- Make sure all the fuses are in place.  He could have pulled one or more.
- check that the spark plug wires are connected tightly to the spark plugs and distributor.
- check the electrical connections on the ignition coil.
- check the electrical connections for the fuel pump and fuel injection if it is injected.
- make sure that if there is a valve for the fuel tank that it is on.

There are many things he could have done to affect it but, the things I listed could have been undone quickly.

---

*EDIT*

Here are some images that might help with identifying where everything should connect.  I snipped them from a manual for [QMB139 (GY6)](http://www.chinesescooterreference.com/pdf/GY6Manual.pdf) that is referenced in [Rory Alsop's](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/users/37/rory-alsop) answer to the question ["Scooter Won't Start"](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/6138/scooter-wont-start) on this site.  If your engine looks like this...

[image: Engine photo]

... Then the following diagrams should apply to your scooter.

---

Here I have highlighted in yellow the fuel/air connection from the carburetor to the engine, outlined in blue the air supply from the intake to the carburetor, outlined in red the fuel line from the tank to the carburetor.

[image: Engine diagram]

---

Here I have highlighted in yellow the fuel shut-off valve for the gas tank.

[image: Shut-off Valve]

---

Here is another view with more parts labeled.

[image: Engine diagram]

---

Here is a helpful trouble-shooting guide that might help get your scooter running again.  I highlighted the starting point in yellow because it wasn't immediately clear to me.

[image: Trouble-shooting]

---

If the air/fuel connection from the carburetor to the engine was loose it might cause non-starting issues.

Comment: there are two hoses that run out of the fuel pump where are they supposed to go??

Comment: i am not sure because im no mechanic at all but the upper hose leaving the carbrtr has been cut and zip tied thats the one that brings fuel into the carbrtr right?

Comment: That hose is normal to have on a carburetor, it may have several, I believe it dumps excess fuel so that it doesn't flood in certain situations (not sure about the reason but, it is normal). It should have another, much larger, hose from the carburetor providing fuel/air to the engine.

Comment: ok so the cut and zip tied hose is normal.. ok the larger hose was lose and not attached to anything when took it off the trailor at home where is it supposed to go?

Comment: i didnt know that the hose was loose when we got home til just now my boyfriend informed me maybe its common sense but im not sure

Comment: the air hose is the one that is disconected not sure where it should go two hoses ..one for gas one for air not sure where the air hose goes

Comment: @hannah I edited my answer to include some, hopefully helpful, diagrams.

Comment: the upper hose that you found cut and zip tied is likely to be a vacuum line, rather than a fuel supply line.

Answer (score 3):

The upper hose that you found cut and zip tied is likely to be a vacuum line, rather than a fuel supply line.

[image: scooter carb with vacuum lines illustrated]
(image credit www.scootusa.com)

If so, the fact that it is cut and plugged should not be causing your failure to start, it is likely an [emissions-related feature](http://scootdawg.proboards.com/post/164753/thread) that is activated when you get off the gas.

Answer (score 0):

Spray some starter fluid into the air intake of the carburator, if it starts, your problem is in carburator or your gas supply. If it doesn't start, your problem is in the spark, compression, timing or electrical.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems. Take oil cap off reservoir, check dipstick for gas in your oil. Anyway go ahead and drain it, more than likely that's your problem. Drain old oil out, new in and it should run like a new one, I know mine sure did.

It is relatively inexpensive. Riding lawn mower did the same thing  the mower was running like crap backfiring etc.  The oil case was half and half oil and gas! Changed my oil and filter and started it and ran like new.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem with my scooter and it was simply the kick stand had to be up.